# Is the MCU origin for the "Avengers” name consistent with the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers, captain-marvel-2019

At the end of *Captain Marvel*, it's suggested that Nick Fury conceived the name for his new crack squad of superheroes from the nickname on the side of Carol Danvers' plane from her US Air Force days:

[image: Carol in her plan with her “Avenger” callsign visible]

Is this namesake for The Avengers consistent with the comics or a movie invention?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a movie invention. In the comics The Avengers are formed by Thor, Hulk, Iron Man and Ant-Man and the Wasp. They do so after they all individually respond to a call of Hulk attacking a train. Loki was interfering with Hulk and Earth in order to lead Thor back to himself. Whilst they start off working solo, they all eventually join together to defeat Loki and coin the name The Avengers at the end. This is all from the very first issue *The Avengers Vol. 1* Issue 1 from 1963.

[image: The Avengers issue showing the formation of The Avengers]

In fact the origin story can’t possibly be the same as in the comics the first Captain Marvel, Mar-Vell, first appeared in 1967 and didn’t originally have anything to do with The Avengers. Therefore, it wasn’t possible for The Avengers to have the same origin. Even Nick Fury didn’t have anything to do with them in the comics from the start.

Comment: Also, in the first Avengers movie, it was implied that the "Avengers" name referred to avenging the death of Agent Coulson, meaning that even in the MCU, there is an inconsistency.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Not really it's called The Avengers Initiative between Fury and the council members before Coulson dies.

Comment: @Hashim Considering my above comment it isn't true though so there wouldn't be much point and it wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: Hehe, Iron Man looks so goofy.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica Kind makes you wonder why he's called "Iron Man" though - That suit clearly appears to be gold or maybe brass or something.  Iron isn't usually yellow, it's black or gray.  Come to think of it, his suit in the MCU isn't iron either, it's - vibranium, I think?  Possibly some non-fictional metal as well but not iron.  Maybe that first one he made in the cave had some iron in it, but the iconic one he uses the rest of the time doesn't.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium_gold

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That suit is actually painted gold and not actually gold. Also the one he uses in the MCU isn't Vibranium, after IW it _might_ be but there's no confirmation that I know of if it is or not.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Okay, still not iron though.  Though I guess "Titanium Gold Man" just doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well I believe that original Mark 1 suit, which is in the comic above, is actually made of iron though I'll have to double check. It was later painted gold because his appearance was "scary" beforehand.

Comment: Wow, good thing for the Avengers that truck was there and hadn't yet left to *dump the radioactive waste into the ocean*.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Before the press conference at the end of *Iron Man 1*, Tony actually remarks that the name is "not entirely accurate" after seeing it in a newspaper headline. IIRC, he does admit that it's catchy, and during the press conference itself he decides to just roll with it, leading to the iconic "I am Iron Man" closing line. How the name came about in the original comics, I don't know.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Iron Man's first appearance had him in a gray suit but it was changed to the gold color in his second appearance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man#/media/File:Tales_of_Suspense_39.jpg

Comment: @gormadoc aye, he paints it gold in Tales of Suspense Issue 40.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that Wikipedia has it as a iron suit. Checking out a YouTube flip-through (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEZBjB4C9n4), it doesn't really specify that it's iron, although they do keep calling it an iron body, but since it's built in virtually the same conditions as in the movie, just in Vietnam, I guess it's all steel. "Steel Man" probably wasn't a great name, considering it was 1963.

Comment: Why could no one write dialogue back then?

Comment: @gormadoc Well, "Steel Man" might have gotten them in trouble with DC, since Superman is often called the "Man of Steel".

Comment: "I pity the guy who tries to beat usT" --The Hulk. "I pity the fool!" --Mr. T

Answer (score 2):

In the comics, Danver's callsign was "Cheeseburger", so we were this close to Nick Fury recruiting people for The Cheeseburger Initiative...

Comment: This _is_ an answer to the question but it’s poorly worded and reads more of a comment. Could also do with you editing in some evidence. Nice  approach from the other angle than my answer though

Answer (score 1):

I think it is from movie only but not so sure. In movie

> [From MCU wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com%20%E2%80%BA%20wiki%20%E2%80%BA%20Avengers)
>   During the starting development of the initiative, the team's original name was meant to be named Protectors, until Fury decided to name it as Avengers, after Captain Marvel's former Air Force pilot call sign.

In comic

> From wikipedia, in ["The Coming of the Avengers" The Avengers 1 (Sep 1963)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_(comics))  The first ever Avengers adventure was Loki trying to get Thor killed by Hulk. He tricked Hulk into destroying a railroad and then diverted a distress signal meant for Fantastic Four to Thor, hoping for a confrontation and demise of his brother by Hulk. However, this distress signal was also received by Ant-man, Wasp, and Ironman, who defeated Loki and resolved the matter. Ant-man at this point realized they worked together and named the group as Avengers

Comment: Actually it was the Wasp, and not Ant-man - see the original comic panels above.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a movie invention; the images from the original comic in the accepted answer say it all, but for what it may worth, here is an excerpt from *[Avengers Assemble: An Oral History of Earth's Mightiest Heroes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0785158014)* by Brian Michael Bendis (Marvel, 2012), which draws directly from the canon of the original comics, and not the movies:

> **Doctor Henry Pym**: Credit where credit is due. The name Avengers came
>   from Janet.
>
> **Janet Van Dyne**: I said that. That was me. I threw it out there.
>   Everyone was spitballing and I said "the Avengers" and everybody
>   grabbed it. So yeah.

Where of course Henry Pym and Janet Van Dyne are the original Ant-Man and the Wasp, respectively, both founding members of the (comics original) Avengers.

Answer (score 1):

## It isn't consistent with the comics...

... not the stories that take place within the prime, [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616) continuity, at least. In that continuity, the Avengers team with Thor, Hulk, Iron Man, etc wasn't actually the first Avengers team, canonically speaking.

A later story established that the *first* Avengers team was formed in 1959 (Marvel Universe-time), before Carol Danvers was even born, never mind in the Air Force. (We know she was in the Air Force prior to the formation of the modern Avengers, since she and Ben Grimm, AKA the Thing, [flew on a mission together](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Before_the_Fantastic_Four:_Ben_Grimm_and_Logan_Vol_1_1) when he was still a pilot himself, before either the Fantastic Four or the modern Avengers had formed.)

Nick Fury (the original version) *was* involved with the formation of the 1959 Avengers, however, he didn't come up with the name; he was told what the name would be by his superiors, and instructed to recruit and lead the team. The dialogue indicates that the orders, and possibly the name of the team itself, came directly from the US President (which would've been President Eisenhower, assuming Marvel Universe history aligns with real world history in that regard).

[New Avengers Vol 2 #9](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_Avengers_Vol_2_9)

[image]

[Avengers 1959 Vol 1 #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_1959_Vol_1_5)

[image]

Also, as noted in Ross Thompson's answer, when the comicbook version of Carol was in the Air Force, her call sign was apparently "Cheeseburger", not "Avenger".

[Ms. Marvel Vol 2 #32](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ms._Marvel_Vol_2_32)

[image]

[image]